# How to configure Eclipse's Package Explorer to display like IntelliJ IDEA's package view?

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ IDEA, the "Project" pane on the left has "View as:", with the following options:

- Project
- Packages
- Scope
- Favorites

If you select "Project" it shows something like Eclipse's "Package Explorer", however if you choose "Packages" and you followed following convention:

- src

  - main

    - java
    - org

      - ...
    - resources
  - test

    - java
    - org

      - ...
    - resources

it displays a view that merges the "main" and "test" folders, thus showing you the unit tests next to their associate classes (the classes they test). This is quite handy IMO, is there a way to do this in Eclipse (3.7.2)?

Thanks!

Comment: Here's an old eclipse bug reprt with screenshots attached: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=173773

Comment: I would love to have a feature like this in eclipse.

Answer (score 4):

This is the way to do it:

Triangle icon -> Package Presentation -> Hierarchial

Note that IntelliJ and AndroidStudio use Gradle style folders, that is `src/main...` and eclipse doesn't yet support Gradle and uses the older style.

[image: Eclipse screenshot]

Comment: Sorry for the delay :-). Thanks for the answer but this is not really what I meant. IDEA _merges_ the main and test view, so you end up with the test classes next to the classes they test (only visually of course).

Comment: No worries man, sorry for my late response, fell asleep. Didn't even know that that was an option in IDEA, good to know!

Answer (score 0):

Screenshots would help for those of us completely unfamiliar with IntelliJ.  Have you tried the Java Browsing Perspective and its Projects and Packages Views?